# I want to disable edit option for recepient and message body in MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

We are building this financial app and we need to implement this feature where app needs to send message for MSISDN verification. What we are doing here is in our `MFMessageComposeViewController` I'm getting a object of private `CKSMSComposeController` class and using following two methods to disable these features

- (void)setCanEditRecipients:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)setTextEntryContentsVisible:(BOOL)arg1;

My question here is will apple reject my app if I use these methods?

Comment: Use of private class is not allowed by Apple, but sometime it might slip thru the review. But in general this would not be allowed, also al we can do is guess you might want to ask Apple directly.

Comment: I know but i am not using any entitlements here i just get that framework using class dump and using it in my project well apple reject it in that way too ?

Comment: You can only submit it and find out, but Apple is pretty thorough in scanning for private classes

Comment: @uvios how are you disabling this is in your code?

Comment: @uvios can you please help me with the sample code ? I too want to disable the recipient and text body message editing